# how to wrap R function as C library

Tags: c, r, api

I'm new to R development, so this may be a trivial question.
I want to extract the do_utf8ToInt from the R source code(raw.c:http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/raw_8c_source.html#l00317), and call it in my C code.How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't C's "atoi" function work just as well?  It's part of the standard library

Answer (score 0):

Use atoi for integer and atol for long integer rather than using raw.c .

If you really want write the function call of do_utf8ToInt and include utf.h in main.c

create utf.h and  write SEXP attribute_hidden do_utf8ToInt(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env);

then compile with c compiler as gcc main.c raw.c -o out

This should work.